# Foundation scss on Rails 5.2 with Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, zurb-foundation, webpacker

How can I set up Foundation scss and JavaScript in a Rails 5.2 application with webpacker?

Here's what I have done so far:

Create new rails application with webpack option:

```
rails new myapp --webpack
```

Do webpacker setup:

```
rails webpacker:install
```

Add "Foundation for Sites":

```
yarn add jquery foundation-sites
```

From there I am kind of lost as to the correct places to put files, what configuration to add, and where it should go.  I was kind of expecting to see a `webpack.config.js` file somewhere.  I see in the [webpacker readme](https://github.com/rails/webpacker) that there is the `app/javascript/src/application.css` file.  Do I just start referencing other files from there and it will all end up compiled/concatenated together?

Comment: Yes you could migrate all of your existing `css` to to `app/javascript/src/*`, you could really replace the need to use the asset pipeline depending on your app

Comment: Check [this](https://medium.com/@coorasse/goodbye-sprockets-welcome-webpacker-3-0-ff877fb8fa79) out, here is a better explanation

Comment: Thanks @jdgray.  That looks like just what I was after.  I'll read over it and give it all a shot.

Comment: Thanks @jdgray, that link helped me get everything working.  I've summed up my steps in a formal answer for the benefit of others that may come across this.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could be of help and thanks for writing this up to help out others :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Putting this answer here for others to see.  It is largely based on [the link](https://medium.com/@coorasse/goodbye-sprockets-welcome-webpacker-3-0-ff877fb8fa79) that @jdgray provided.

Create a new rails application with webpacker:

```
rails new myapp --webpack
```

You don't need to run `rails webpacker:install` manually as I'd initially thought as it gets run from the prior command anyway.

Change directory into your rails app and add Foundation (and jquery, which the foundation plugins need):

```
yarn add jquery foundation-sites
```

That will leave you with an application capable of using webpack, but nothing actually in-use yet.

The bulk of things will end up in the new `app/javascript` directory, but it makes sense to rename that when putting more than just javascript in it.

Rename that to `app/webpack` and then edit `config/webpacker.yml` to change the `default.source_path` value to also be `app/webpack`.  Any name can be used of course, but `webpack` seems like a decent choice.  That bit of config will look like this:

```
default: &default
    source_path: app/webpack
    source_entry_path: packs
    public_output_path: packs
    cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
```

Webpacker uses "packs" as entry points to add to your views/layouts.  In the `app/webpack/packs` directory you should have `application.js` already.  Create a file named `stylesheets.scss` in `app/webpack/packs` to handle stylesheets.  More will be added to these later.

Next create the directories `app/webpack/src/javascript` and `app/webpack/src/stylesheets` which will be the places to put all of your usual javascript and scss code.

To set up configuration some foundation stuff, create a directory `app/webpack/src/stylesheets/foundation_config` and create the file `foundation.scss` in it.  Inside that file put the following lines, which will reference foundation and make a few specific foundation features availble:

```
@import '~foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss';
@include foundation-global-styles;
@include foundation-grid;
```

That new `foundation.scss` file alone won't do anything and needs to be references by a pack.  Add the following line to `app/webpack/packs/stylesheets.scss`:

```
@import '../src/stylesheets/foundation_config/foundation'
```

Now you have a pack file, which will load your source file, which loads foundation.  The last thing to do is to use that pack file in your layout.  In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` add the following line in the head tag:

```
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'stylesheets' %>
```

Note: In the development environment (at least with Rails 6.0.2) this wil not be enough to call the css file into from the head tag. Since `config/webpacker.yml` is set to:

```
default: &default
        ...
        extract_css: false
```

If that is set to false, you can either set it to true or have both the `javascript_pack_tag` and the `stylesheet_pack_tag` in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. With the second solution the css file is injected after page loading into the head tag by the compiled js.

With all of that, Fondation will be working via webpacker.  The structure will of course allow for any other javascript of stylesheets to be used as well, but this question was just about Foundation so I'll stop here.  Thanks again @jdgray!